# Bill Calculation using SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I've having some problems as I'm trying to calculate the total amount for a consumption. 
so for example:
for the first 20 watt is charged at 0.40
for the next 20 watt is charged at 0.80
and 0.90 for each watt in excess of 20 watt

I've tried doing something on my own but the calculation is wrong and is there any way to optimize the query as i do not wish to do the calculation at the main select statement. is subquery a better option?

I'm using Oracle as DB engine

```
SELECT CustomerName, previousRead, newRead, newRead-previousRead AS Consumption, 
(((newRead-previousRead-100)*FR)+((newRead-previousRead-200)*SR)+((newRead-previousRead-200)/200)*TR)as TotalBill 
  FROM (
        SELECT C.firstName||''||C.lastName as CustomerName, R.newReading previousRead,
               lead(R.newReading) OVER (PARTITION BY R.meterID ORDER BY R.dateVisited) AS newRead, B.firstconsumptionRate as FR,
               B.secondconsumptionRate as SR, B.firstconsumptionRate as TR
        FROM reading R, serviceaddress S, electricmeter W, customer C, rate A, nonresidentialrate B
           WHERE W.meterID = S.meterID
           AND R.meterID = W.meterID
           AND A.rateID = S.rateID
           AND B.rateID = A.rateID
           AND C.custID = S.custID
           AND C.custType = 'Non-residential'
           AND  r.datevisited >=  TO_DATE('01-06-2014','DD-MM-YYYY') 
           AND r.datevisited < TO_DATE('31-07-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')
        )where newRead is not null;
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
custID              INTEGER NOT NULL,
firstName           CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
lastName            CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
NRIC                CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
custType            CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
badStatus           CHAR(25) Default 'Good',
CONSTRAINT cust_Pkey PRIMARY KEY (custID),
CONSTRAINT cust_type CHECK (custType IN ('Residential', 'Non-residential')),
CONSTRAINT custBadStatus_type CHECK (badStatus IN ('Late Payment', 'Non Payment', 'Good'))
);

CREATE TABLE Reading (
readingID       INTEGER NOT NULL,
meterID         INTEGER NOT NULL,
dateVisited     DATE NOT NULL, 
newReading      NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT reading_Pkey PRIMARY KEY (readingID),
CONSTRAINT reading_AltKey UNIQUE (meterID, dateVisited),
CONSTRAINT reading_meterID_Fkey FOREIGN KEY (meterID) REFERENCES Meter (meterID),
CONSTRAINT checkReading CHECK (newReading > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE Rate (
rateID          INTEGER NOT NULL,
rateApprDate    DATE NOT NULL,
rateEffDate     DATE NOT NULL,
rateType        CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT rate_Pkey PRIMARY KEY (rateID),
CONSTRAINT rateType CHECK (rateType IN ('Residential', 'Non-residential')),
CONSTRAINT validDate CHECK (rateApprDate < rateEffDate),
);

CREATE TABLE NonResidentialRate (
rateID                      INTEGER NOT NULL,
firstconsumptionRate        NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL,
secondconsumptionRate       NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL,
thirdconsumptionRate        NUMBER(5,2) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT nonResidentialRate_Pkey PRIMARY KEY (rateID),
CONSTRAINT nonResidentialRate_rateID_FK FOREIGN KEY (rateID) REFERENCES Rate (rateID)
);

CREATE TABLE ServiceAddress (
svcAddID            INTEGER NOT NULL,
meterID             INTEGER NOT NULL,
custID              INTEGER NOT NULL,
rateID              INTEGER NOT NULL,
street              CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
city                CHAR(35) NULL,
state               CHAR(2) NULL,
zipPostalCode       CHAR(9) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT serviceAddress_Pkey PRIMARY KEY (svcAddID),
CONSTRAINT serviceAddress_meterID_Fkey FOREIGN KEY (meterID) REFERENCES Meter (meterID),
CONSTRAINT serviceAddress_custID_Fkey FOREIGN KEY (custID) REFERENCES Customer (custID),
CONSTRAINT serviceAddress_rateID_Fkey FOREIGN KEY (rateID) REFERENCES Rate (rateID),
);

CREATE TABLE Meter (
meterID             INTEGER NOT NULL,
SerialNum           CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
installationDate    DATE NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT waterMeter_Pkey PRIMARY KEY (meterID),
CONSTRAINT waterMeter_Altkey UNIQUE (SerialNum)
);
```

The customer can be both of residential and non-residential and each of them has a service address. The meter is unique to each service address and the reading is stored in a different table.
There are 2 kinds of rates as well, their are different kind of rates for residential and nonresidential.

As for the reading, I did not create a new attribute for previous reading because it can be obtained tru the previous month reading

hope this makes my question clearer.

Comment: you need to show us the tables and explain their relationships if you want someone to look at this query.

Comment: @DavidChan Hi David, I've shown the tables that are required for the query itself. hope this actually helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you can give it a try..

```
SELECT CustomerName, previousRead, newRead, newRead-previousRead AS Consumption, 
    CASE WHEN newRead-previousRead <= 100
          THEN (newRead-previousRead)*FR
          WHEN newRead-previousRead <= 200
          THEN 100*FR + (newRead-previousRead-100)*SR
          WHEN newRead-previousRead > 200
          THEN 100*FR + 100*SR + ((newRead-previousRead)-200)*TR 
      END as TotalBill
      FROM (
            SELECT C.firstName||''||C.lastName as CustomerName, R.newReading previousRead,
                   lead(R.newReading) OVER (PARTITION BY R.meterID ORDER BY R.dateVisited) AS newRead, B.firstconsumptionRate as FR,
                   B.secondconsumptionRate as SR, B.thirdconsumptionRate as TR
            FROM reading R, serviceaddress S, meter W, customer C, rate A, nonresidentialrate B
               WHERE W.meterID = S.meterID
               AND R.meterID = W.meterID
               AND A.rateID = S.rateID
               AND B.rateID = A.rateID
               AND C.custID = S.custID
               AND C.custType = 'Non-residential'
               AND  r.datevisited >=  TO_DATE('01-06-2014','DD-MM-YYYY') 
               AND r.datevisited < TO_DATE('31-07-2014','DD-MM-YYYY')
            )where newRead is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Were it me, I'd probably use a `CASE` statement and structure the code for clarity rather than trying to eke out every last cycle of performance (unless you're really in an environment where you need every last cycle)

```
(CASE WHEN newRead-previousRead <= 20
      THEN (newRead-previousRead)*0.40
      WHEN newRead-previousRead <= 40
      THEN 20*0.40 + (newRead-previousRead-20)*0.80
      WHEN newRead-previousRead > 40
      THEN 20*0.40 + 20*0.80 + (newRead-previousRead-40)*0.90
  END)
```

Now, obviously, there are ways to optimize this (by, for example, computing newRead-previousRead in the inner query once rather than potentially needing to compute it 4 times in the `CASE` statement).  And this is not a particularly flexible option if you want to be able to change the billing structure frequently (in which case the tiers and rates would need to be in a separate table that you read).  But it's hopefully a relatively clear expression of the computation.